# Replace hour with 12am in date format

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  String date = "31-01-2023";
  String hour = "12:30";
  
  String completeData = "${date} ${hour}";
  String tempHour = hour.replaceAll(":", ".");
  DateTime tempDate = new DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm").parse(completeData);
  print("Formatting date: ${tempDate}");
  
}
```

When I print the **Formatting date**:

`2023-01-31 00:00:30.000`

I replace the 12 with 00, but I need to keep 12.

If I pass 11,13,14 or more it works correctly

Comment: If you replace ":" for ".", you dont set correctly  the hours and the minutes because the Dateformat works by hh:mm and your "30 minutes" are setted like "00:00:30.000" seconds

Comment: @Maikzen but I don't use tempHour...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from the intl documentation:

```
/// The following characters are available in explicit patterns:
///
///     Symbol   Meaning                Presentation       Example
///     ------   -------                ------------       -------
///     ...
///     h        hour in am/pm (1~12)   (Number)           12
///     H        hour in day (0~23)     (Number)           0
///     ...
```

Since you are using `hh:mm` pattern, the `12:30` gets converted to `00:30`. What you can do, is use this pattern `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm` - it should work.